# C++ : code::block does not recognize included header

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors, include, codeblocks

I got the following code in C++ :

```
in main():

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << function(1) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

in my source code file:

```
#include <math.h>

int function(int number)
{
int value(number + 2);

return value;
}
```

And in my header called "math.h" :

```
#ifndef MATH_H_INCLUDED
#define MATH_H_INCLUDED

int function(int number);

#endif // MATH_H_INCLUDED
```

When I try to compile it I got the error : "function" was not declared in this scope

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`<math.h>` is a standard header file, and the use of `#include <math.h>` makes it prefer the standard header file path over the current directory, unless you give your current directory precedence (by using the `-I` switch to specify an include path, as an example).

If you use `#include "math.h"` instead, the compiler will search the current directory first. Alternatively, you can rename your header file to something different from `math.h`.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <…>`:
the **<**…**>** means "search in the include path".

`#include "…"`:
the **"**…**"** means "search in the actual path, if you don't find the header, then search in the include path".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `#include <math.h>` searches for the standard library's version, not yours. Use the double quotes instead of the angle brackets:

```
#include "math.h"
```

Answer (score -1):

The error says "function" not declared in this scope -- I notice that in all of the uses of what I suspect you intend to mean as 'function', you spell it as 'fonction' with an 'o'. Double-check that you have consistent spelling between uses and declaration.